# POST : get_responses API not giving required data

Tags: rest, api, survey, surveymonkey

Ideally the call to this API - https://api.surveymonkey.net/v2/surveys/get_responses

should give a json response like this :

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "questions": [
                {
                    "answers": [
                        {
                            "col": "3024965133",
                            "row": "3024965139"
                        },
                        {
                            "col": "3024965134",
                            "row": "3024965140"
                        },
                        {
                            "col": "3024965135",
                            "row": "3024965141"
                        },
                        {
                            "row": "0",
                            "text": "Other!"
                        }
                    ],
                    "question_id": "316084770"
                },
                {
                    "answers": [
                        {
                            "col": "3024965125",
                            "row": "3024965122"
                        },
                        {
                            "col": "3024965124",
                            "row": "3024965123"
                        }
                    ],
                    "question_id": "316084761"
                },
                {
                    "answers": [
                        {
                            "row": "3024959616"
                        }
                    ],
                    "question_id": "316083321"
                },
                {
                    "answers": [
                        {
                            "row": "0",
                            "text": "This is an open answer"
                        }
                    ],
                    "question_id": "316083320"
                },
                {
                    "answers": [
                        {
                            "col": "3024962639",
                            "row": "3024962638"
                        },
                        {
                            "col": "3024962640",
                            "row": "3024962637"
                        },
                        {
                            "col": "3024962639",
                            "row": "3024962636"
                        }
                    ],
                    "question_id": "316084090"
                },
                {
                    "answers": [
                        {
                            "row": "3024964761",
                            "text": "9"
                        },
                        {
                            "row": "3024964762",
                            "text": "1"
                        }
                    ],
                    "question_id": "316084724"
                }
            ],
            "respondent_id": "2500019027"
        }
    ],
    "status": 0
}
```

But when I am requesting the API for responses to my survey by specific respondents, I am getting a blank array.

[image]

Note : I am able to see the proper responses via SurveyMonkey UI console.

Answer (score 0):

If you use API v3, you may get a better error message:

https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-id-responses

It seems your issue could be that you have more than 100 responses for that survey and you can only access the first 100 on a basic plan from what I see from the logs.

If that's the case the solution would be to

1. Upgrade your plan
2. Delete some old responses
3. Duplicate the survey maybe?

Again I would recommend moving to V3 of the API for a better experience.